# Where do I get the Certificate?

Tags: android-c2dm

While the Third party server connects to C2DM Google Server, I think there is SSL or TLS Connection in between. if so, where do i get the certificate that will be used in between for handshaking?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this certificate from Google C2DM server with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect android.apis.google.com:443
```

I assume it is signed by a certifying authority that you can verify.

Comment: Thank you I will check on it !